# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '345/add/Caipirinha'

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

So, I'm working on a bar tab application in Django, and when it came down to insert some data into the tabs I'm getting the error:

> ValueError at /tabs/345/add/Caipirinha/
>
> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '345/add/Caipirinha'

I have tried some of the solutions provided before on Stackoverflow but with no success.

Here are some of my files:

**models.py**

```
class Tab(models.Model):
  number = models.IntegerField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length='50')
  tabdate = models.DateTimeField('date created')
  consumed = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ConsumedRelation')
  def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name


class ConsumedRelation(models.Model):
  tab = models.ForeignKey(Tab)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
  count = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=1)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.tab) + " | " + str(self.count) + " " + str(self.product)
```

**views.py**

```
def addproduct(request, tabnumber, product):
  tabnumber = Tab.objects.get(number=number)
  productadd = Product.objects.get(name=str(product))
  add = ConsumedRelation.objects.create(product=productadd, tab=tabnumber, count=1)
  add.save()
  context = {'tabnumber': tabnumber, 'product': productadd}
  return render_to_response('addproduct.html', context,     context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**addproduct.html**

```
{% for product in productlist %}
<a href="add/{{ product }}/"<li>{{ product }}</li></a>
{% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^tabs/add/(?P<tabnumber>\d)/(?P<product>\d)/$', 'barcomandas.views.addproduct'),
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: The traceback doesn't contain information about which function generated it?

Comment: `<a href="add/{{ product }}/"<li>{{ product }}</li></a>` this should be `<li><a href="add/{{ product }}/">{{ product }}</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) in your template so that Django generates the proper URL.

```
<a href="{% url 'barcomandas.views.addproduct' tabnumber=sometabnumber product=product %}"<li>{{ product }}</li></a>
```

Comment: +1 Right, you should try to avoid hardcoding urls in your html templates, saves you hassle :).